# Difference between TileWMS and WMTS

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, wmts, qgis-openlayers-plugin, tile-map-service

Map is working fine with TileWMS, but I was wondering is it better to use WMTS to display map as tiles or TileWMS is as good. What are the trade-offs of using either one.

Comment: The tiled WMS specification https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WMS_Tiling_Client_Recommendation was written by the open source community before WMTS existed. Both solutions are fundamentally the same - client can send an URL  so the the server can send the response directly from the cache. WMTS is an OGC standard and it has wider support in software. Also WMTS supports some advanced features, for example more flexibility in defining the tile matrixes.